# Fixed Header not properly working

Tags: html, css, fixed

I want to create a fixed header for my website. This is currently what I have: http://www.hidesertheat.com/test/index.html

I need the header to appear over my slider. What am I missing? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give z-index property for the class ' header_menu '. I checked in firebug with following property and worked fine.

```
.header_menu{
   z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.header_menu {
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url("http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/112/b/a/header_bg_by_destinyjade-d7flhv4.png");
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
background-size: auto auto;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10000;
```

}